# Can I populate an Outlook actionable message with data from the recipient's calendar?

Tags: outlook, adaptive-cards, actionable-notification

I'd like to generate an actionable message sent to each person in my organization with calendar information. Ideally, it would do the following for each person:
1. Display the appointments from that person's calendar for that day
2. Place a checkbox next to each so the person can indicate if he or she will attend, along with a "submit" button.

I don't have administrative access to each person's calendar so my code can't retrieve each person's calendar information. My hope is the Actionable Message on the client can perform the action of retrieving each person's data and showing it to them. All the mailboxes are in Office 365.

Is something like this possible?